# CSS-only Polygonal Border

Tags: css, borders

For example, how could I recreate the "Ask Question" button in pure CSS without images?

[image]

There is [this method here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/22471/how-can-i-create-this-irregularly-shaped-border-with-pure-css-no-images) but I'm looking for a normal no-fill stroke-only border.

I've been able to do it [using inline SVG](http://jsfiddle.net/9w3gp/5/), but I was hoping there was a way to do it without SVG, using nothing but CSS styles (perhaps something like the border tags in the above question).  Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Don't think it can be done with one object other than utilizing before and after pseudo classes.

Comment: Psuedo-classes would be fine, I think.  I just don't want to cram a bunch of SVG into my stylesheets

Comment: I *believe* this is possible with just pure `css`. At least I thought it was, the first time I saw it. Turns out it's a `png` background.

Comment: ...and: doesn't this question belong at Stack Overflow?

Comment: I was wondering about that too, but then I saw this question: http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/469/what-do-we-do-with-html-css-questions-that-are-code-based-but-simple-and-focused

Comment: I agree, zelv, that it's an issue that's still debated :) Note that I didn't vote for migration. Personally, I'd like to have Q's like these, not in the least because SO could be more... welcoming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed this with just css, with pseudo-elements and the `transform:` property. It ain't very pretty, though, and needs some tweaking the numbers to be snug and symmetrical.

[image]

```
.foo {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    border-top: 2px solid orange;
    border-bottom: 2px solid orange;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    color: white;
}

.foo:after, .foo:before {
    content: " ";
    border-top: 2px solid orange;
    border-right: 2px solid orange;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;
}

.foo:before {
    transform: rotate(216deg) 
     skewY(20deg);
    margin-left: -42px;
    margin-top: -3px;
}

.foo:after {
    transform: rotate(36deg) 
     skewY(20deg);
    margin-left: 18px;
    margin-top: -3px;
}
```

Not tested in anything beyond Firefox on W7, and it might not be pixel-perfect in other browsers.

Comment: Nice solution, thanks! The ability to also have a transparent background is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Can do it with 2 divs and before and after pseudo classes.....

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/4ZeCz/2465/)

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
        Test Container
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    width: 200px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    border-left: none;
    padding: 4px;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 40px;
}

.container > div {
    line-height: 40px;

    /*text styles */
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #aaa;
}

.container:after,
.container:before,
.container > div:after,
.container > div:before {
content: '';
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 100%;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-style: solid;
}

.container > div:after {
top: 0;
border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff;
border-width: 24px;
}
.container > div:before {
top: -1px;
border-color: transparent transparent transparent #f00;
border-width: 25px;
}


.container:after {
left: -48px;
border-color: transparent #fff transparent transparent;
border-width: 24px;
}
.container:before {
top: -1px;
left: -50px;
border-color: transparent #f00 transparent transparent;
border-width: 25px;
}
```

This is untested in anything but Chrome 37/Mac.
I'm not really certain if all that CSS is better than SVG.

Comment: Wrote the code for my answer and then came back to gd.se and noticed it's fundamentally the same as yours. .. :/ We apparently write css similarly, because I _swear_ that I didn't look at your code before writing mine. Then again there aren't that many ways to write it, unless you're super chaotic with it. Here's my [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/yeMYt/).